# Trouble setting up a usb-serial HP Laserjet 6MP printer

Tags: printing, hp

I have an old HP Laserjet 6MP that I am trying to use with an IEEE 1284 -> USB cable. I plug it in and turn it on before booting into Kubuntu and I get some likely candidates in /dev/: parport0, parport1, lp0, lp1

Following advice I've seen elsewhere on the web, I have tried setting the URI to all combinations of [parallel, serial, usb]:/dev/[parport0, parport1, lp0, lp1] but haven't been able to get a test page to print ever.

Any ideas on how else I can trouble shoot this?

Comment: I ran dmesg and got output like this: [69623.668702] uss720: async_complete: urb error -32
[69623.668725] get_1284_register: usb error -32  Repeated over and over. The 1284 part means its about my usb-serial cable...? Perhaps it is faulty?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line

```
blacklist uss720
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

This worked for me on Fedora 17 and 18, where the `uss720` module caused me problems. Once I did this and rebooted, Fedora found my Laserjet6L and configured it automatically.